# Composition of Derangements

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

What is the probability that composing two random derangements yields another derangement?

A slightly more specific question: suppose we start with a given derangement and compose it with all derangements. What is the distribution of cycle structures?

Addendum: perhaps it would be worth explaining why this question popped up in the first place. I am interested (purely out of curiosity) in the expected number of "steps" it takes to reach the identity permutation where each step is composition with a random derangement. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279924/expected-number-of-steps-to-order-first-n-integers) for a related question (the only different is starting with a random permutation).

If you like to have "context": this is like asking how many steps it takes for $n$ penguins/koalas/beings with terrible memory to find their room, which they will recognize upon being inside, but which is otherwise indistinguishable. That's why I originally began with an arbitrary permutation, in any case.

Comment: Derangement is a permutation without fixed points, right?

Answer (score 21):

An array of $k$ permutations of $n$ letters such that each pair are derangements of each other is a $k\times n$ Latin rectangle. If $L(k,n)$ is the number of $k\times n$ Latin rectangles, then the probability you ask for is $n!\, L(3,n)/L(2,n)^2$. The value of $L(2,n)$ is $n!$ times the number of derangements. The value of $L(3,n)$ doesn't have closed form but there are recurrences and summations; see [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1a1) for a survey.  The asymptotic value of $L(k,n)$ is $e^{-\binom k2} (n!)^k$ for fixed $k$, from which you can see that the asymptotic value of the probability is $e^{-1}$.

I don't know the answer to your second question, though I rather suspect that the average cycle structure of the product of two random derangements is quite similar to the cycle structure of an unrestricted random permutation.

Comment: It's interesting that the asymptotic probability is the same as the asymptotic probability a random permutation is a derangement. Composing two random derangements does not give a random permutation though - the identity has probability $1/D_n$ of appearing.

Comment: It seems to be minimised for $n=5$ at a probability of $\frac{69}{242} \approx 0.285$.

Comment: "though I rather suspect that the average cycle structure of the product of two random derangements is quite similar to the cycle structure of an unrestricted random permutation." - this would, to some extent, be checkable by simulation.  (If I feel so inclined later I may elaborate on this comment.)